# Solidity: using low level call function on an EOA

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, eoa

Say I have a contract with a method that does a low level call on an address `_addr` assuming the target address is a contract with a certain method `isValid()`:

```
contract Dummy {
    function doCall(address _addr) public returns (bool) {
        return _addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("isValid()");
    }
}
```

What happens if the address `_addr` is not a contract but an EOA? Trying it in Remix indicates that the call returns `true` when `_addr` is an EOA.

If this is indeed the case can someone explains or point me to the part of the documentation where this is exlained?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this call should succeed. In general, a call will succeed unless the receiving address reverts. The difference between an EOA and a contract is that the contract has code (and so that code might revert, e.g. if it doesn't have a given function defined and lacks a fallback function). An EOA doesn't have code, so it can't possibly revert.

Comment: @smarx Could you post your comment as an answer so people can find it more easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*moving my comment to an answer as requested*)

Yes, this call should succeed. In general, a call will succeed unless the receiving address reverts. The difference between an EOA and a contract is that the contract has code (and so that code might revert, e.g. if it doesn't have a given function defined and lacks a fallback function). An EOA doesn't have code, so it can't possibly revert.