# How is Uniswap's way of calling the balanceOf function of an ERC20 gas optimized?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap, uniswapv2

What is the redundant extcodesize check and returndatasize check that is mentioned here?

```
/// @dev This function is gas optimized to avoid a redundant extcodesize check in addition to the returndatasize check
function balance0() private view returns (uint256) {
    (bool success, bytes memory data) =
        token0.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(IERC20Minimal.balanceOf.selector, address(this)));
    require(success && data.length >= 32);
    return abi.decode(data, (uint256));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "extcodesize check" is a check that decides whether the target address (`token0` in this example) is a contract (non-zero code size) or a EOA (zero code size). Low level calls to EOA [are going to succeed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56743/solidity-using-low-level-call-function-on-an-eoa), but the returned data size is going to be zero. The optimization is to check just if the returned data size is correct instead of checking whether `token0` is a smart contract before calling the `balanceOf` function.